# Add another UrlHandlerMapping to Spring data rest

Tags: spring-data-rest

I'm having a normal spring-mvc project and I'm also building a `rest` module as a separate jar file. The goal is when I have the `rest` jar in my classpath to have the normal website mapped to `/` and the spring-data-rest repositories mapped to `/rest`. For the `rest` module I have defined `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` as well as a `WebApplicationInitializer` and it all works fine.

So now I want to add some more `URLs` to the `rest` module (like `/synchronize`, and `/authenticate`, etc.) but as soon as I add controllers in the `rest` module, they are picked up by the parent application context (the one for the website `/`). I tried specifying them as bean in the `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` but still they are picked up by the other parent context and the filters of the parent context are fired. And when I access the spring-data-rest through `/rest` no filters are triggered.

So I was wondering: is there a method I could override in the `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` so that I can add extra url handler mappings?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that you want to have another controller advertised as part of Spring Data REST's root hypermedia.

To do so, you need to create another class in your app like this:

```
@Component
class DogifierResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<RepositoryLinksResource> {
    @Override
    public RepositoryLinksResource process(RepositoryLinksResource objects) {
        objects.add(new Link(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
                .build()
                .toUriString()
                .concat("dogifier/{id}"), "dogifier"));
        return objects;
    }
}
```

This will create a hypermedia entry with rel="dogifier" that lists /dogifier/{id} as the URI. It will also prefix it with the proper URN, etc.

Of course, you can use Spring HATEOAS to [link to a controller method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas#building-links-pointing-to-methods) without having to specify the actual path by hand. That would reduce maintenance and encourage better hypermedia controls.

Comment: Hi Greg, this is great - I can add the controllers to the SDRs root JSON. However, my question is more on how to skip the filters on the /frontend. So I have a WAR application at /frontend and it has some filters defined.The war includes my rest.jar in WEB-INF/lib and the rest.jar includes my custom /dogifier controller. When I call /frontend/rest/product for instance (product repository exposed via SDR) the filters are skipped. However when I call /frontend/rest/dogifier (my custom controller) the filters are NOT skipped.

Comment: This is because /frontend scans packages for [at]Configuration and then it finds my [at]Configuration in the rest.jar and it adds the Controllers in the parent application context (the one in /frontend). So I want to add my controllers to SDR but so that I can skip the filters defined in /frontend

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude those controllers from the classpath scanning of the parent context. Just follow the [instructions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-scanning-filters) in the Spring documentation.